# Does double z=x-y guarantee that z+y==x for IEEE 754 floating point?

Tags: c#, floating-point, ieee-754

I have a problem that can be reduced to this problem statement:

> Given a series of doubles where each is in the range `[0, 1e7]`,
>   modify the last element such that the sum of the numbers equals
>   exactly a target number. The series of doubles already sums to the
>   target number within an epsilon (1e-7), but they are not ==.

---

The following code is working, but is it guaranteed to work for all inputs that meet the requirements described in the first sentence?

```
public static double[] FixIt(double[] input, double targetDouble)
{
    var result = new double[input.Length];
    if (input.Length == 0) return result;

    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        sum += input[i];
        result[i] = input[i];
    }

    double remainder = targetDouble - sum;
    result[result.Length - 1] = remainder;
    return result;
}

var arr1 = Enumerable.Repeat(Math.PI / 13, 13).ToArray();
var arr2 = FixIt(arr1, Math.PI);

Debug.Print(Math.PI.ToString("R")); //3.1415926535897931
Debug.Print(arr1.Sum().ToString("R")); //3.1415926535897922
Debug.Print(arr2.Sum().ToString("R")); //3.1415926535897931
```

A previous version of this question asked about modifying the first element, but modifying the last element simplifies the problem to a known sum and a known target, leaving us with just the question of whether `last = target-sum` implies that `sum+last == target`.

(Without NaN of course, and the restrictions on ranges imply some restrictions on `last` as well that might help.)

<sub>Regarding the real problem: We've had this problem surface a number of times in a variety of ways, but what we are trying to do at the moment is reduce the floating point error that crops up due to numerical instabilities in a linear programming solver (Coin-OR CBC). For example, there are 6 variables which all must be in the range [0,X] and the sum of the variables must also be X. Due to numerical instability, the solver occasionally returns slightly negative values and values that do not sum to exactly X. We've overcome the negative number issues - now just trying to resolve the sum to X issue. (Yes, there may be constraints that are being disobeyed by us changing the results, but making sure these numbers sum to X is of higher priority, where the other constraints are not as important.)</sub>

Comment: This code ignores the first input element. Is that what you want?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, because array is meant to sum to a particular known number. So at least one number must be altered if == is not already true.

Comment: I have edited to alter the last element. I feel like editing the first element will not work because the order in which the doubles are summed will matter. By altering the last element, I think it is more likely to work.

Comment: Huh?  You can modify the last one?  That's obviously simpler, because now you directly control one of the inputs to the final add-and-round step, and can exactly calculate the other one.  I thought this was a homework assignment or something when I edited to put part of it in a quote block; is that not the case? Anyway, I had been going to suggest that subtracting from the target in reverse order might leave you with a first element that "worked". But I'm not sure if it was (provably?) always solvable given the limits on size, and the max correction. Not sure if no list-length limit mattered.)

Comment: @PeterCordes No it's not a homework assignment. It's a real world problem. Does that mean it will work by altering the last element instead of the first?

Comment: @MineR the arithmetic (and the consequences of the data type) is (are) identical no matter which element you choose to change

Comment: I think it might, given all your restrictions.  You could test to see if every representable `double` over that +-1e-7 range is hittable, or if `last = target - sum` can round in a way that makes `last + sum != target`.  You've reduced your question to that, you should edit your title.    (use `nextafter` to get the next representable `double`, if C# has that).  Bedtime for me, though.

Comment: @MarcGravell: are you sure?  That would definitely not be true if negative values were allowed; `x + 2^53  - 2^53` would round it to the nearest integer (assuming it was positive), destroying any fine adjustments you could make in the first element.  But changing the last element could still potentially let you hit a fine range of targets.

Comment: @PeterCordes I will concede you could probably get *closer* by changing the last element, since any intermediate large rounding problems are "done". Assuming that the *sum* will always be done in the strictly forwards order! But: the fundamental problem will be the same; it is hard to guarantee any specific level of "correctness" (at least in terms of how humans think rounding should work)

Comment: @MarcGravell: I agree that there's probably an X-Y problem here; requiring exact equality for an FP sum is problematic in the first place, and will make it impossible to use anything but strict FP (so the `Sum()` can't auto-vectorize with SIMD or hide FP latency with multiple accumulators.) @MineR: see also https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/, which is part of a very good series of articles you should read.  But regardless, there's still an interesting IEEE-754 question here that I'm not sure of the answer to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`z = x-y;` does not guarantee `z+y == x`, and there is not always a solution for the problem of finding a `z` such `z+y == x`. A proof follows.

We assume IEEE-754 binary floating-point arithmetic with rounding to nearest, ties to even. The basic 64-bit format is used, but the result holds for other formats. Note that the 64-bit format uses 53-bit significands, meaning that only numbers with 53 or fewer significant binary digits can be represented.

Consider a target `x` equal to 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. Let `y` be 2<sup>−53</sup>. Then, after `z = x-y;`, `z+y == x` evaluates to false. The arithmetic details are shown below, but:

- `z = x-y;` sets `z` to 1, and then `z+y` produces 1, which is less than `x`.
- If we increase `z` to the next representable number,  1+2<sup>−52</sup>, then `z+y` produces  1+2<sup>−51</sup>, which is greater than `x`.
- So there is no value of `z` that makes `z+y == x` true.

Details:

The mathematical result of `x`−`y` is 1+2<sup>−53</sup>. As this has 54 significant bits (from 2<sup>0</sup> to 2<sup>−53</sup>), it is not representable, and the computed result of `x-y` must be rounded. The two nearest numbers are 1 and 1+2<sup>−52</sup>. The ties-to-even rule produces the former number, 1, as the low bit of its significand is 0, while the low bit for 1+2<sup>−52</sup> is 1.

Thus `z = x-y;` sets `z` to 1.

Then the mathematical result of `z`+`y` is 1+2<sup>−53</sup>. As above, this is rounded to 1, so the computed result of `z+y` is 1. So `z+y == x` compares 1 to 1+2<sup>−52</sup> and produces false.

Furthermore, no value of `z` could make the comparison true. If we increment `z` by the smallest available step, from 1 to 1+2<sup>−52</sup>, the mathematical sum of `z`+`y` is then 1+2<sup>−52</sup>+2<sup>−53</sup>. This is midway between the two representable numbers 1+2<sup>−52</sup> and 1+2<sup>−51</sup>. The former has a low bit of 1, and the latter has a low bit of 0, so the computed result of this `z+y` is 1+2<sup>−51</sup>, which is of course not equal to 1+2<sup>−52</sup>.

Floating-point addition is weakly monotonic, so there are no values of `z` that would produce 1+2<sup>−52</sup> for `z+y`.

Comment: Thanks very much - tested the example, and it does not work, at least in C# on my hardware.

Comment: @MineR: The circumstances permitting this result are quite rare. A number of additional conditions might preclude it and solve your problem. For example, if `y` is at least half of `x`, then `x-y` is exact, and `z+y == x` is necessarily true. If `y` is at least one binade (exponent value) higher than 2^-52 times `x`, then there is enough wiggle room that `z` will be such that `z+y == x` is true even though `x-y` is not exact. And, if the low bit of `x` is zero, I think the situation in this answer cannot occur. So, if your practical problem can be narrowed down a bit, there may be a solution.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like we can make the fix work by doing chopping off the low bit as you suggest, as that level of precision doesn't matter in our case.

Comment: @MineR: I think this problem only happens with extreme differences in order of magnitude, which might not occur in your real use-case.  Adjusting the *smaller* number should always be able to hit a desired target, so maybe `if(last > sum_of_previous*(1ULL<<40))`, adjust the 2nd-last element instead, because that will let you make fine changes to the smaller input to the final sum.  (But beware that it could mean a huge relative change in the tiny element, or even make it negative.  Perhaps you use that if condition to look for numerically problematic cases...  2^40 is just a number I made up)

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. Here's a concrete counter-example; coded in Python, but you can easily repeat the same experiment in C#:

```
>>> x = 0.24999916553497312
>>> y =  1.0000153779983518
>>> z = -0.7500162124633787
>>> z == x - y
True
>>> z + y == x
False
```

Here's a small counter-example with `x`, `y`, `z` all positive:

```
>>> x = 0.4500000000000001
>>> y = 0.20000000000000004
>>> z = 0.2500000000000001
>>> z == x - y
True
>>> z + y == x
False
```

Comment: The OP was restricting things to non-negative (including z, because of the restriction that the target sum be within a small margin of the actual sum).  Negative numbers make precision-losing cancellation much more easily possible than with Eric's case of the last number (`z`) being orders of magnitude larger than the sum of the previous ones (`y`).

Comment: @PeterCordes No problem; added a counter-example with "small" yet positive values. The values are all close "enough" as OP requested.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact, by definition (unless you're only dealing with integers (edit for correctness: up to 2<sup>53</sup> i.e. 9007199254740992)); you will **always** have rounding discrepancies. If you want the rounding to match what *humans* expect: use `decimal` instead of `double`. If you do the same thing with `decimal`, it will work correctly for any set of numbers that aren't pathological in terms of the decimal digits.

Comment: I know it's not exact; but I want to use double for performance reasons. The reason I need it to sum up is because I am dividing a large number into many parts, and I need the sum of these parts to == the whole. Is there literally no way to accomplish this using double?

Comment: Will add that's because `decimal` is base 10 and `double` is base 2.  Base 2 numbers cannot accurately represent all base 10 numbers.

Comment: @MineR any time you do arithmetic on a `double` (such as the sum and subtract): you're introducing the likelihood of tiny rounding discrepancies due to the actual numeric representation being used. It usually doesn't matter how fast you can get the wrong answer. If you don't want to use `decimal`, you could just round the `double` to some arbitrary precision ... i.e. 0.99999999999999989 taken to 8 decimal places is 1. Further... frankly, any time you try to test for exact equality on two `double` values: *your code is probably wrong*. That's *usually* not a correct test to perform.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.  The OP is asking if this algorithm will always work for IEEE-754 binary64 `double`, given the restrictions in the question (non-negative being most important, so catastrophic cancellation can't happen, making it plausible that a `double` first element might exist for every representable sum).  But it doesn't say that the "desired" target can't be less than the sum of the other elements, requiring a negative first element...  e.g. a target of `1e-200` is not going to be achievable by changing the first element, not enough significand bits.

Comment: This answer does not speak to the question asked, and its assertion that floating-point arithmetic always has discrepancies is false.

Comment: @EricPostpischil "and its assertion that floating-point arithmetic always has discrepancies is false" - if you're using floating point arbitrarily, and not *anticipating* rounding discrepancies: you're using it wrong; I appreciate you're being pedantic here (technically correct - the best kind of correct), but: as a general guidance, I would argue that this statement is more helpful than unhelpful; if you don't think it speaks to the question: great! please add an answer that *does*, and we'll all be better off

Comment: Integers are one case where you can get exact results from binary FP.  There are others, including the trivial `0.25 + 0.25 == 0.5`.  (binary floating-point formats can exactly represent fractional numbers where the denominator is a power of 2).  Anyway sure, as general guidance that's fine, but this question is asking a *specific* question.

Comment: @PeterCordes I already covered integers in the answer; for the "others" - see comment above: "arbitrarily" - if you already know the values ahead of time (so that you can say "hah, look, we're in the case where it works exactly") - then you wouldn't be doing the sum at runtime *at all*

Comment: I don't understand the motivation / use-case for the question either, but it's still interesting.  My edits to the question made it more specifically focused on the narrow technical question, somewhat invalidating your answer that suggested a different type. :/

Comment: The fact that this answer makes a false statement is not pedantic. Floating-point practitioners make use of exactness when available and of other properties of floating-point arithmetic to design and prove code. Misleading and false answers like this one are detrimental.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'd argue that this makes the question-edit invalid, rather than your (after-the-fact) edit invalidating an existing answer :)

Comment: Cleaned up a bunch of comments here, because they'd gotten too contentious and were tending towards being unpleasant. Regardless, having this information buried in the comments, where no one will look, is not helpful. Eric said he was working on an answer; I'll let him address the issues there, where he can give them a proper treatment. For those who don't think Marc's answer is helpful, feel free to downvote, as always.